# Unit testing of controller ends in error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I have an MVC 3 app that I'm trying to unit test.  I read the example from [this page](http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2009/05/16/132131.aspx) that shows how to mock the controller.  Here is my test code:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestAddStudy() {
        var controller = new AdminController();
        var httpContext = FakeHttpContext();
        var context = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()), controller);
        controller.ControllerContext = context;

        var request = Mock.Get(controller.Request);
        request.Setup(r => r.Form).Returns(delegate() {
            var nv = new FormCollection();
            nv.Add("Name", "Test Study");
            nv.Add("IsDefault", "selected");
            return nv;
        });

        var result = controller.CreateStudy(request.Object.Form as FormCollection) as ActionResult;

    }

    public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext() {
        var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

        httpContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        httpContext.SetupGet(ctx => ctx.Request.RequestType).Returns("POST");
        httpContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
        httpContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
        httpContext.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
        httpContext.SetupGet(ctx => ctx.User.Identity.Name).Returns("testClient");

        return httpContext.Object;
    }
```

Here is the code inside the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateStudy(FormCollection form) {
        Study newStudy = new Study();
        TryUpdateModel(newStudy);
        newStudy.CreatedBy = CurrentUser;
        newStudy.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        studyRepository.Edit(newStudy, CurrentUser);
        return RedirectToAction("EditStudy", new { id = 1 });
    }
```

It fails every time on the TryUpdateModel statement with an Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.  What am I doing wrong...or more importantly, how can I get this simple method unit tested?

Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.ValidationUtility.CollectionReplacer.GetUnvalidatedCollections(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.ValidationUtility.GetUnvalidatedCollections(HttpContext context, Func`1& formGetter, Func`1& queryStringGetter)
   at System.Web.Helpers.Validation.Unvalidated(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Mvc.FormValueProviderFactory.<.ctor>b_*0(ControllerContext cc)
   at System.Web.Mvc.FormValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.<>c*_DisplayClassc.b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.TryUpdateModel[TModel](TModel model)
   at Controllers.AdminController.CreateStudy(FormCollection form) in C:\Visual Studio Projects\Controllers\AdminController.cs:line 254
   at Tests.UnitTest1.TestAddStudy() in C:\Visual Studio Projects\Tests\UnitTest1.cs:line 32

Comment: Please include the stack trace.

Comment: I just want to suggest you to use MVC Contrib's TestHelper : http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper it will be easyer to write test.

Answer (score 0):

Does this line actually return an object or is it null?

```
Study currentStudy = ctx.Studies.Where(p => p.StudyID == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

You might want to check for null before calling `TryUpdateModel(currentStudy)` like this:

```
Study currentStudy = ctx.Studies.Where(p => p.StudyID == id).FirstOrDefault();
if (currentStudy != null) {
    TryUpdateModel(currentStudy);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, posted the wrong method.  I'm actually working on the CreateStudy method.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stack trace, it looks like the exception is being thrown within the call to  `TryUpdateModel(newStudy)`. I can only imagine that either the `Study` object which is being returned by `new Study()` does not satisfy the requirements of `TryUpdateModel()` or that there is some dependency that ASP.NET MVC requires in order to make this method work, which is missing in your test context but present in your runtime context (assuming that the controller method is working for you when you run a functional test).

If the method works during a functional test, then the latter explanation must hold. Again, looking at the stack trace here:-

> Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.ValidationUtility.CollectionReplacer.GetUnvalidatedCollections(HttpContext
>   context) at
>   Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.ValidationUtility.GetUnvalidatedCollections(HttpContext
>   context, Func1& formGetter, Func1& queryStringGetter) at
>   System.Web.Helpers.Validation.Unvalidated(HttpRequest request) at

It looks like the `HttpRequest` is being used to perform some validation. I would guess that your mock request object needs some further method/property return values to be set up. In particular, I guess it must at least needs to return `NameValueCollection` instances from it's `Form` and `QueryString` properties, even just empty ones. It's reasonable to assume that the validation code within MVC is assuming that these properties never return null values. Given that you haven't set up return values for these properties on your mock objects, this would explain why a `NullReferenceException` is being thrown deep within the MVC code.

Try adding these lines to your mock creation code:-

```
request.SetupGet(req => req.Form).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
request.SetupGet(req => req.QueryString).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
```

Depending on the requirements of your test and/or controller, you may find that you will have to add some values to at least one of the `NameValueCollection` instances, in order to more accurately mock the content of a real request.

Comment: Added the code and still can't unit test it.  Odd thing is, the method works fine when using the application.  I just can't seem to get it to work inside of a unit test.

Comment: Do you get the same exception and stack trace?